# Where is mistake in Plotly Python plot?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, seaborn

I have a code like below:

```
goodCredit = data[data["Risk"] == 'good']
badCredit = data[data["Risk"] == 'bad']

bar1SA = go.Bar(
    x = goodCredit["Saving accounts"].value_counts().index.values,
    y = goodCredit["Saving accounts"].value_counts().values,
    name='Good credit')

bar2SA = go.Bar(
    x = badCredit["Saving accounts"].value_counts().index.values,
    y = badCredit["Saving accounts"].value_counts().values,
    name='Bad credit')


bar1CA = go.Box(
    x=goodCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().index.values,
    y=goodCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().values,
    name='Good credit')

bar2CA = go.Box(
    x=badCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().index.values,
    y=badCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().values,
    name='Bad credit')



data = [bar1SA, bar2SA, bar1CA, bar2CA]

fig = tls.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                          subplot_titles=('Count Saving Accounts','Count Checking account'))

fig.append_trace(bar1SA, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(bar2SA, 1, 1)

fig.append_trace(bar1CA, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(bar2CA, 1, 2)


fig['layout'].update(height=700, width=800, title='Saving Accounts and Checking account Exploration based on risk')
py.iplot(fig, filename='SAiCAdistribution')
```

and the result of this is like below:

[image]

Where is mistake in the code, because as you can see the second plot is not good, it should me similar like the first plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say similar I am assuming you want them to both be bar charts. If so then switching

```
bar1CA = go.Box(
    x=goodCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().index.values,
    y=goodCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().values,
    name='Good credit')

bar2CA = go.Box(
    x=badCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().index.values,
    y=badCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().values,
    name='Bad credit')
```

to

```
bar1CA = go.Bar(
    x=goodCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().index.values,
    y=goodCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().values,
    name='Good credit')

bar2CA = go.Bar(
    x=badCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().index.values,
    y=badCredit["Checking account"].value_counts().values,
    name='Bad credit')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: haha... wow it is impossible that I did not find this solution, thank you !!